# All entries of representation matrix of $A$(character $0$ ring)-linear map is integer?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $A$ be a ring of character $0$, and let $M$ be an $A$-module.
Let representation matrix of $A$-linear map $\varphi : M \rightarrow M$ be $N$.
$N$'s matrix entries are in $A$.
In other words, representation matrix of an $A$-linear map is in $M(A)$.

If we admit this, $M$ also can be seen as module over arbitrary subring of $B$. So all entries are in $\mathbb Z$... .
(Every character $0$ ring contains $\mathbb Z$ as subring).
What am I missing?

Comment: Of **characteristic $0$**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with $M=A=\Bbb{Z}[i]$, $\varphi(a)= i a$ is represented by the $1\times 1$ matrix $\pmatrix{i}$ and the $2\times 2$ matrix $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$  acting on $\Bbb{Z}^2\cong M$ as $\Bbb{Z}$-module.

You need $M$ to be a finitely generated $A$-module, and choose some generators, to represent your endomorphism by a matrix.

Comment: Oh, I see. We can take Z-entry matrix, but the sizes of them are different ! For example, Tl(E)(Tate module) can be certainly seen as Z-module, but is representation matrix is not 2×2 ! (infinite?)